# conjure-up: How can I set juju bootstrap-series to bionic

Tags: juju, maas, snap, conjure-up

I'm working to standup MAAS and OpenStack on Ubuntu 18.04.  MAAS is installed and managing my hardware and I am now attempting to install OpenStack via conjure-up.  When conjure-up calls juju bootstrap is is requesting the default series 'xenial' as specified in the *juju.py* file.

If I call juju from the command line it uses 'bionic'.  I can't find any documentation on how to pass the bootstrap-series value to juju from conjure-up.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know if you delete the image from the the MAAS controller it will install 18.04. I haven't have any luck trying to get 18.04 + working on nodes, it always picked 16.04 when it sorta works.

Answer (score 0):

You have more control of what series you would like to deploy (controller only):

```
$ juju bootstrap --help | grep series
--bootstrap-series (= "")
    Specify the series of the bootstrap machine

$ juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=xenial
Clouds
aws
aws-china
aws-gov
azure
azure-china
cloudsigma
google
joyent
localhost
oracle
rackspace

Select a cloud [localhost]: hit enter here for localhost as default choice

Enter a name for the Controller [localhost-localhost]: test1 

Creating Juju controller "test1" on localhost/localhost
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.4.6 for amd64
To configure your system to better support LXD containers, please see: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/production-setup.md
Launching controller instance(s) on localhost/localhost...
 - juju-324cd0-0 (arch=amd64)          
Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance
Fetching Juju GUI 2.14.0
Waiting for address
Attempting to connect to 10.102.181.77:22
Connected to 10.102.181.77
Running machine configuration script...
Bootstrap agent now started
Contacting Juju controller at 10.102.181.77 to verify accessibility...
Bootstrap complete, "test1" controller now available
Controller machines are in the "controller" model
Initial model "default" added
$

$ juju machines -m controller
Machine  State    DNS            Inst id        Series  AZ  Message
0        started  10.102.181.77  juju-324cd0-0  xenial      Running
```

Above creates a controller with xenial. To create one with bionic run:

```
$ juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=bionic
```

2) start conjure-up, select software to deploy and then you will be asked if you want to create new controller or use existing one. Select the controller created in step 1 and continue.

You could also bootstrap controller manually to lxd 
https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.4/en/clouds-LXD

and when it launches by default as you mentioned it would be bionic. Quick and easy.

Hope it will help.
Thanks
B